# With default resources in the drawable folder (MDPI sized) what's the point of the drawable-mdpi folder?

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I've a full set of images at the various different pixel densities, and I need to put bitmap resources into the drawables folder (at MDPI) to use as default resources (to prevent crashing on pixel density devices I've not catered to, e.g. xhdpi), but that means duplicating the resources in the drawable-mdpi into the drawable folder.

So as duplication is clearly bad, I'm wondering whether I should just delete the drawable-mdpi folder, and keep my MDPI resources in the (default) drawable folder

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to duplicate your resources. A good practice is to do the following:
- Put all non image-based drawables inside res/drawable/ (for instance all your XML drawables)
- Put all image-based drawables (images and 9-patches) inside res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, etc.

Comment: Merci Romain. So with images in drawable-ldpi/mdpi/hdpi, with no bitmaps in drawables itself, will the app not blow up on an xhdpi device, or does it scale up the hdpi bitmaps? I thought default bitmaps were required in the drawable folder (at MDPI scale)

Comment: I'd love to separate the xml resources from image resources as you suggest here, however, from what I understand you can't do this if you support ldpi devices and only have mdpi optimized resources.  If we drop ldpi support then we could.

Comment: I disagree. In my opinion this will not work if they introduce new formats like xxhdpi. I would need to take care all the time and be aware of new formats. If there are no default images in drawable, the application would crash on xxhdpi because of missing resources.

Comment: @Bevor, that is incorrect. If a new format like xxhdpi is introduced, Android will pick drawable from the closest density (xhdpi for instance) and scale the images up.

Comment: @RomainGuy Ok, didn't know that. Nevertheless, my solution is to omit the mdpi folder and to use the standard drawable, values,.. folder. So I have a "default" folder. At least I will implement my new app in this way (I already read on another thread that omitting the mdpi folder is also a solution)

Comment: You should put all of your bitmap resources under an explicit density qualifier.  Yes, the unqualified directory is assumed to be mdpi; this is only there for compatibility from before the density qualifier was introduced, and there is *no* reason to put bitmaps there.  Putting your bitmap under -mdpi does not cause any compatibility issues.  (More specifically: all of these -mdpi and other qualifiers are *only* processed and understood by aapt; the platform itself doesn't care at all what the directory is.)

Answer (score 1):

All I would say, is that obviously Romain guy is correct about using drawables to keep xml files in and then moving image resources into the relevant mdpi, hdpi and ldpi folders, the only time I'd go against this is when you wish to target 1.5 devices.

The reason for this is that because 1.5 has no recognition for the -hdpi, -mdpi and -ldpi tags, it ignores them and picks resources (seemingly randomly) from each folder, so instead you have to add the following flag -hdpi-v4, -mdpi-v4, -ldpi-v4, this will then make those folders accessible by 1.6+ versions of Android forcing 1.5 to only see the drawable folder, at which point you need to have all your resources in drawable, which then removes the need to have the drawable-mdpi folder.

However, since 1.5 is getting on a bit and such few devices have it, it makes more sense to target 1.6+ and ignore this complication.

Comment: The thing that was confusing me was that for some drawables I only had a bitmap in the hdpi folder, and the app was blowing up, saying it couldn't find resources. I created mpdi and ldpi versions and so it all works ok, but seemed odd Android doesn't pick the closest image it has and scale it.