# Does Android override resources files in ascending or descending order?

Tags: android

Android has various folders it goes through to set up its resources. For example, `values-small, values-normal, values-large, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi` etc. How does Android go about pulling from these folders? Does it start with the smaller (`values-small` or `drawable-mdpi`) and work its way up to the larger (`values-large` and `drawable-xhdpi`) or does it work in reverse starting with the larger and then overriding with the smaller?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think that it goes through each folder. I think it uses device/system attributes to determine what the appropriate value is for each individual device. For example, xlarge screens are considered to be anything at 960dp x 720dp or higher, so anything that meets that requirement would use values for large screens. Might find some more at http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and again I am not sure, just seems the way it is done from what I have read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great overview from the [official Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch):

> When selecting resources based on the screen size qualifiers, the
>   system will use resources designed for a screen smaller than the
>   current screen if there are no resources that better match (for
>   example, a large-size screen will use normal-size screen resources if
>   necessary). However, if the only available resources are larger than
>   the current screen, the system will not use them and your application
>   will crash if no other resources match the device configuration (for
>   example, if all layout resources are tagged with the xlarge qualifier,
>   but the device is a normal-size screen).

So to answer your question:

> Does it start with the smaller (values-small or drawable-mdpi) and
>   work its way up to the larger (values-large and drawable-xhdpi) or
>   does it work in reverse starting with the larger and then overriding
>   with the smaller?

It will look at the current dpi and attempt to retrieve the resource from that directory. If not available, it will only search the lower densities in a descending order. It will not search the higher densities.